# Print a magento text field attibute in 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have set a new text field attibute up (download) and would like to print it on the list page.

I've tried everything to get it to print inculding these below, has anything changed in 1.7?

```
<?php $_product->getData('download'); ?>
<?php echo $item->getDownload(); ?>
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('download'); ?>
```

any ideas?

Comment: its ok i sorted it, was a problem in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try $_product->getDownload()? That should work for text field attributes in Magento 1.7.